# Place not found when setting group place

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I want to set this location/page: https://www.facebook.com/HHU.de/ as a group location for a new group, I've created. I cannot find it in the list when setting it, however. I can set that location in a status. What prevents it from being set as a group location? I can find other universities, so it shouldn't be the type of the location.